# swffit, where to put the code?

Tags: browser, scrollbar, flash, browser-scrollbars

there is a stupid question:

Where in HTML should I put the following code of swffit?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swffit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
swffit.fit("my_flash", 1000, 590);
//-->
</script>
```

I try to use swffit with no success. I have the javafile put to the same folder as the index.html. Is there something I'm not doing right?

Answer (score 0):

The <s>code</s> markup you posted goes between the `<head>` tags (though in practice most browsers will not complain if you put it just about anywhere, the head is the correct place.)